# Excel: Convert calendar week (format ww.yyyy) into date

Tags: excel, date-conversion

I need to convert an Excel calendar week date into the actual date.

Excel calendar week format = ww.yyyy (e.g. 31.2014); 
Expected output = 7/28/2014  (return the Monday of the week)

What formula should I use ?

Comment: How can you get a day out of a weeknumber (i.e., the 28 of 7/28/2014)?  Are you looking for the Sunday or Monday of the weeknumber?

Comment: Also in the future, a simple Google search is much more productive (for both you and the answerers).  First result for "convert weeknumber to date" is http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1684-excel-convert-week-number-to-date.html

Comment: Awesome. I have *exactly* the same formula! Actually, this is quite idiomatic.

Comment: I was looking for a solution for specifically having the date formatted as ww.yyyy. And yes, I did check other resources beforehand.

Comment: For week 1 of 2015 do you use 01.2015 or 1.2015? How are your weeks defined, are they "ISO weeks" or something else, e.g. when does week 1 of 2015 start (with ISO week numbers that would be 29 Dec 2014)

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a pain: there's no direct function. If A1 contains the year, and A2 contains the week number then,

`=MAX(DATE(A1,1,1),DATE(A1,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,1,1),2)+(A2-1)*7+1)`

will return the date corresponding to the Monday of that week in that year.

To test it, use `=WEEKNUM()` and `=YEAR()` on the computed result, along with `=TEXT(,"DDD")` to prove it's a Monday.

Answer (score 2):

If @Bathsheba's response works for you, you can do everything in cell B1 with the following command

```
=MAX(DATE(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)),1,1),DATE(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)),1,1),2)+(MID(B1,FIND(".",B1)+1,2)-1)*7+1)
```

This allows you to put YYYY.WW in B1 and it splits it up for you in the calculation.